# Change color of an active menu item in Foundation 6 with SCSS

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm wondering whether there's an `scss` variable associated with the `color` of an `activated menu item` (e.g. `Top Bar`).

Doing a:

```sh
grep --color=auto -R 'active' *scss
```

I see among the found lines this:

```sh
scss/components/_menu.scss:    .active > a {
scss/components/_menu.scss:      background: $menu-item-background-active;
scss/components/_menu.scss:      color: $menu-item-color-active;
```

I'm not too sure if these are the right lines to alter in my custom `SCSS` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite anything in your app.css file. Just put it after all the `@include` lines.

```
.menu {
  .active > a {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```